# How to fix my modulus filter to correctly calculate the amount of each bill?

Tags: python, modulus

I mainly code in Python, and I've been working on this fake ATM machine. You can enter a value you would like to withdraw, and it would record it on `Transaction History.txt` and calculate the amount of each bill required to reach your value.

Everything works as expected, except for the modulus filter...

Here is the modulus filter I created to calculate the amount of each bill required to reach your value:

```
import math
import time

amount = input("Input: ")
print("Withdrawing €%s..." % amount)
time.sleep(0.5)
amount = float(amount)

b500 = math.floor(amount / 500)
r = amount % 500
c200 = math.floor(r / 2)
r %= 2
c100 = math.floor(r / 1)
r %= 1
c50 = math.floor(r / 0.5)
r %= 0.5
c20 = math.floor(r / 0.2)
r %= 0.2
c10 = math.floor(r / 0.1)
r %= 0.1
c5 = math.floor(r / 0.05)
r %= 0.05
c2 = math.floor(r / 0.02)
r %= 0.02
c1 = math.floor(r / 0.01)
r %= 0.01

if amount > 0:
    print("Dispensing %d 2EUR coin(s), %d 1EUR coin(s), %d 50cent coin(s), %d 20cent coin(s), %d 10cent coin(s), %d 5cent coins, %d 2cent coins, and %d 1cent coins." % (c200, c100, c50, c20, c10, c5, c2, c1))
elif amount == 0:
    print("Cannot withdraw 0EUR.")
else:
    print("Cannot withdraw negative values.")
```

*The above code is a modified snippet of the whole ATM.*

When you run it in a compiler, and you enter a value such as `2.4`, the output is `Dispensing 1 2EUR coin(s), 0 1EUR coin(s), 0 50cent coin(s), 1 20cent coin(s), 1 10cent coin(s), 1 5cent coins, 2 2cent coins, and 0 1cent coins.`, which totals up to `2.39EUR` instead of `2.4EUR`.

Please help, I am stuck. I've been at this for two days already, and I can't seem to locate the issue (which is why I am here on StackOverflow).

Comment: You never loop back after calculating one iteration of the modulo operator. In your example of `2.4`, ideally you would want `1 2EUR`, and `2 20cent coins`. But after the first `20 cent coin`, you never give it a chance to go back and try to `r %= 0.5`, it will just move on and try `r %= 0.2`. Essentially it only gets one chance at each coin. You'll need to loop it somehow after each modulo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because float numbers aren't nice, rounded numbers. Though the console might tell you that `2.4%2` is equal to `0.4`, internally the number is stored as 0.39999999... So, at some point, you would to for example `0.4%0.2`, expecting to receive 0, but the actual modulus would be `0.3999999...%0.2`, which would return `0.19999999`, but displaying `0.2`.

The easy way to solve this is always rounding your modulus operations. Instead of `r%=0.2`, write `r=round(r%0.2, 1)`. Here you say to round the return of `r%0.2` to a number with one decimal case.

The proper way when dealing with currencies is to use the `Decimal` class. You just have to convert your numbers to `Decimal` then all operations would be rounded properly.

Another way would be dealing with cents instead of fractional numbers. In this case, `2.4` would be `240` cents, then you just work with integers as operators.

Comment: Okay, will do! Thanks a lot for the suggestion! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Woops sorry (first time on StackOverflow ;D ). It should be green now.